# what the error supposed to be in give code i could not figure this out?

Tags: php

```
$upload = new uploadObject('songs');  

$upload->title = $data['upload_data']['title'];
$upload->description = $data['upload_data']['description'];
$upload->tags = $data['upload_data']['tags'];
```

Notice: Undefined variable $data

Comment: The error message is quite descriptive. What is `$data` ?

Comment: FYI Notice, not Error

Answer (score 0):

you need to define `$data` at the top like..

```
$data="";
// then your other code
```

Comment: that what it supposed to be but when i delcare the variable it gives me the notice
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 

Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in